# About Notepad++ Regex

Tags: regex, xml, search, replace, notepad++

I want to find and replace with regex bu couldnt apply the right codes. If i can do it with 3 lines it will be wonderfull but if i cant one line will be ok for me too.

Find "`<info>image1.jpg</info>`" and Replace "`<info1>image1.jpg</info1>`"

Find:

```
<information>
<info>image1.jpg</info>
<info>image2.jpg</info>
<info>image3.jpg</info>
</information>
```

Replace:

```
<information>
<info1>image1.jpg</info1>
<info2>image2.jpg</info2>
<info3>image3.jpg</info3>
</information>
```

Edit :

It is so usefull. Thanks a lot for the answer. I wrote image1.jpg for shorting the code. It is more longer. Is there universal codes for the middle like (image(\d+).*?) Understood that .*?) is for file extension but couldnt use image(\d+) for the real link. If you can tell me what they it means i can use forever this codes. :)

```
<info>http://www.image.com/Uploads/abcdef-221b-33f4-22d4-12g13cd3bg98.jpg</info>
<info>http://www.image.com/Uploads/abcdef-6ca5-4d2e-97c1-25f536fd2ab48.jpg</info>
<info>http://www.image.com/Uploads/abcdef-542a-41c0-96c7-1878ce48df4f.jpg</info>
</information>
```

Comment: You should show what you've tried

Comment: That is why you have to show your exact input and output. The regex will change

Comment: You are right , ı didnt know it will change the regex code, so i shorted the link for making easier the answer. If you can help or teach me one more time with original link i will be happy. or thanks for your interest again.

Comment: What should be the answer in the last case --> `1878ce48df4f.jpg` . There is no number here

Comment: Yes the file name is abcdef-542a-41c0-96c7-1878ce48df4f.jpg. There is no number in originally.

Comment: Then what should we replace "<info>" with?.

Comment: Ok i understood how the code is working now. Its taking the number from image number. I want to replace info1, info2, info3.... by increasing automatically. I took your time. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find : `<info>(image(\d+).*?)</info>`

Replace with : `<info\2>\1</info\2>`

Works in TextWrangler, should work on Notepad++ as well.